# Filezilla upload to server error

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have some problems trying to upload a module to my server.

I get this in the console:

```
Error:  Failed to open "C:\Users\greg.FWLTD\Desktop\Projects\Data migration tool\Products_Data_Migration_from_Magento_1_to_Magento_2-1.0.0\Products_Data_Migration_from_Magento_1_to_Magento_2-1.0.0\app\code\community\CapacityWebSolutions\ExportProduct\Model\Resource\Exportedfile\Collection.php" for reading
Error:  File transfer failed
```

In the `Failed Transfers` tab, for reason I get: `Could not start transfer`

Could anyone direct me?

Comment: What are the permissions on that file and the containing directory?

Comment: The file has `Full control`, `Modify`, `Read & Execute`, `Read`, `Write`. And the folder has all of that + `List folder contents`, however, in the general tab the attribute is set to `Read-only(Only applies to files in folder)`. Could that be the reason I can't upload it? Also how can I change it? There are only two options here, `Read-only` and `Hidden`.

Comment: That all looks OK. Some other problem ...

Comment: Hymmm... any other ideas?

Comment: Nope. Nothing springs to mind :/

Comment: Does that folder contain more files? Your path exceeds 255 characters, some products might have issues with that. A possible easy fix would be to move the Projects directory directly to your C:\ drive or at least your "inner" `Products_Data_Migration_from_Magento_1_to_Magento_2-1.0.0` directory.

Comment: You are amazing! It was driving me insane!

Comment: If you want to put that as answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this ticket found in [FileZilla](https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/6193), the FileZilla server cannot handle files exceding `260 characters` path length. Your path has `269`